# iPad / iPhone SSH client with ProxyJump, no subscription, and decent privacy policy?

Tags: ios, ssh

I'm looking for an SSH client for iPad and iPhone which have the following features:

- **ProxyJump:**, so one can use a Bastion host.
- **Free or one-time-payment:** I'm not interested in paying a yearly subscription for this.
- **Decent privacy policy:** A terminal app should not talk to data-brokers or otherwise use data for marketing or promotions.

So far, I've tried / considered the following software, but none of them make a perfect trifecta:

| App | ProxyJump? | No subscription? | Privacy? | Comments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| iSH | ❌ | ✔️ | ✔️ | iSH is slow and installing SSH is difficult |
| Prompt 2 | ❌ | ✔️ | ✔️ |  |
| a-Shell | ❌ | ✔️ | ✔️ |  |
| Blink Shell | ✔️ | ❌ | ✔️ | Free version periodically mandates *shaking your device* to continue. |
| Termius | ❓ | ❓ | ❌ | [Uses personal data for marketing.](https://www.termius.com/privacy-policy) |
| Shelly | ❓ | ❓ | ❌ | [Uses personal data for marketing.](https://www.iubenda.com/privacy-policy/674938) |

Unfortunately, I do not own a Mac, so I cannot compile-locally and sideload Blink myself, even though it is open source.

Does anyone here know of a good SSH client that checks these three boxes?